# asp.net UpdatePanel, (there is also telerik) error

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have asp.net 2.0 web application. On my production server I "randlomly" cant reproduce the path error on my page which uses UpdatePanel and RadComboBox telerik control:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB7.2; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.2)
Timestamp: Mon, 14 Nov 2011 10:37:17 UTC

```
Message: Sys.ScriptLoadFailedException: The script 'http://www.mySite.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=K-bZ_cYro-TWH0gbbmdTlkin59eWVsDQYopNlGtfNYd9aZQqi22u0d_A5dwpqMXbaJR99E08UDAgSF7tPCaP0mpZH35-uv4YYRWnSX0mxLsZPGu-58i2Nrmb8UHNokeftpIW9wTPOvZOJJq4cLYfu3iV8EQ1&t=634475972033675436' could not be loaded.
Line: 5
Char: 36564
Code: 0
URI: http://www.mySite.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=qLp9xu4UQDU3wBn-LSS2bLlqFvY6K78U8bVN8Ado2bzP7ytCoarS92INypIVz4z3TbmYil4Bsu_vW_InD5PMZRw-1WJbZIeVuS8TpTL23g_GrfQ29YBzoTaZWO2T3kxiSZPDfk0zqFyT9qKbsPGSfNc4kjnqG509cXg82kYxOpPDJjpf0&t=634532699342719389
```

Do You know any cause for this error ? Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a stylesheet missing.  I added:

```
string sRequestUrl = Request.Url.ToString();
```

To my error message to get it to output the file in question.  Is this a case of you having a script manager which is consolidating (minifying) stylesheets and JavaScript files into one and you are losing the Request Url in the .axd?  If you do turn off the consolidation (minification) and you should get the exact file from the Request Url.

If that is the problem.

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand. So what should I do ?

Comment: I also dont understand why it happens randomly, not always

Comment: If you are using the Telerik RadScriptManager it will combine all your JavaScript and CSS files into an AJAX call: http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/scriptmanager.aspx

Comment: It looks from your error that you need to turn off enablescriptcombine: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/p_telerik_web_ui_radscriptmanager_enablescriptcombine.html